Как обновить access_token в oauth2 дискорда
Я понял как получить access и refresh токены для авторизации через дискорд (с помощью эндпоинта https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token).
Но по моим наблюдением access токен быстро истекает.
Как его обновить? Можно ли просто отправить  запрос на эндпоинт с refresh токеном и получить новый access?

Я не смог найти ответ. Поэтому решил использовать только access токен, и никак его не обновлять. И не так уж быстро он истекает
